# In Excel-VBA, is there any way to get the process name 'I am running in?

Tags: excel, vba

'In Excel-VBA, is there any way to get the process name
'I am running in? For example, in Excel VBA I am
'executing a sub mysub(). Within this sub I want
'to cache the sub name "mysub" in to a variable
'for certain use later. How it can be achieved?

```
    Sub mysub()

    getmysubname = howtoget 'this is my variable to catch the sub name

    Debug.Print getmysubname 'sub name is printed in debug window

    End Sub
```

'Kindly provide the method to do this

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. There is no generic way, but to use a variable that's named like the sub you're in.

```
public CurrentSub as string
sub mysub()
    CurrentSub ="mysub"    '        do as you wish after
end sub
```

Comment: I knew about this method but I wanted some thing like this, if available or possible; myvar=ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.CurrentSub.name

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to get the VB Project Module your `Sub` is in, if you use a variable (or constant) to save your `Sub` name.

See the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub mySub()

Const PROC_NAME = "mySub"

Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim i As Long
Dim ModuleName As String

Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject

' loop through all modules, worksheets and other objects in VB Project
For Each VBComp In VBProj.VBComponents
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule

    ' loop through all code line inside current module
    For i = 1 To CodeMod.CountOfLines
        If Len(CodeMod.Lines(i, 1)) > 0 Then
            ' if the name of current sub is found within the current code line
            If InStr(CodeMod.Lines(i, 1), PROC_NAME) > 0 Then
                ModuleName = CodeMod.Name '<-- get the current Module name
                MsgBox "Sub " & PROC_NAME & " found in " & ModuleName & " module"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next i
Next VBComp

End Sub
```

In order to access the VB Project Module, you need to follow the 2 steps below:

**Step 1**: Add "**Trust access to the VBA project object model**" , go to ***Developer*** >> ***Macro Security*** >> then add a **V** to the ***Trust access to the VBA project object model***.

[image]

**Step 2**: Add Reference to your VB project, add "**Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3**"

[image]

**That's it, you are ready to give it a go !**

Comment: But (a) that returns the module name, not the sub name (i.e. OP wants to get the value `"mySub"`, not `"Module1"` or whatever), and (b) it will (if I read it correctly) return the first occurrence of the `PROC_NAME` which might be in a completely different module (e.g. where the subroutine is being called from).

Comment: @YowE3K  I know, I wrote what currently I was able to do, still thinking on how to get the Sub I'm in. But still, you got to admit it's still is nice (much nicer than the answer above)

Comment: I'll admit it's **nice** - but completely off-topic - LOL.  (I've always wished that there was a way to access the Stack Trace in VBA - if you find a way you will be the first person to do so.)

Comment: Think of the options my code does provide, let's think you have a large project with 10-15 modules and 5 User_Forms. Now you are looking to find where a certain Function you are calling to is located, you could use this code to find out where each `Function` and `Sub` is placed.

Comment: I could also use `Edit/Find` or, more likely, `View/Definition` (because usually when you are looking for where a Sub is placed it is because you have come across a mention of it in the code and you want to go and see what it does).  I can't think of much use of knowing the code module at run-time.